# Magento - Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting

Tags: fatal-error, magento-1.7, nested

I don't know what is causing this error. I was working on a custom module on my Magento store and didn't check the homepage of the store regularly. Out of the blue today I am getting this error on my homepage.

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\indieswebs\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 1045
```

The funny thing is there is NO 1045 line number in this file! So I am guessing it's some sort of looping error. But I don't know what is causing it. Can anyone help me figure out what might be causing this particular error and how can I remove it?

Edit:I deleted the cache from the store and reloaded the homepage. The error has changed now. It says:
    **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261904 bytes) in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\indieswebs\lib\Zend\Db\Select.php on line 281**

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

The error only come when you installed xdebug.

Use following setting in php.ini
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200

Comment: I set the nesting level to 1000. It still shows the same error.

Comment: Before set nesting, Did you check XDebug installed or not on your server? Also Please check phpinfo that value is properly set or not.

Also if you do not need for xdebug than you should comment that extension.

Comment: xdebug was installed but i commented it in php.ini file. But still the error remains. Plus it takes so much time to load the homepage! And after that much time it'll return the fatal error.

Comment: can you try with xdebug.max_nesting_level=1000

Answer (score 0):

I got this in my Collection.php model, and the culprit turned out to be the call to `parent::__construct()`. Once I remmed it out the error went away. PS: Raising xdebug nesting level limit did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve a related issue (that causes the same error message) by checking the files in [webroot]/app/etc/

It was happening (on enterprise edition) because

```
config.xml
enterprise.xml
```

were missing from that directory. Once I put them back, that fixed this problem.

I also read elsewhere that a malformed local.xml might cause this issue.

On enterprise edition, use something like:

```
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[some_user]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[some_pass]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[database_name]]></dbname>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
```

On CE, use something like:

```
    <default_setup>
        <connection>
            <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
            <username><![CDATA[your_user]]></username>
            <password><![CDATA[your_pass]]></password>
            <dbname><![CDATA[your_db]]></dbname>
            <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
            <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
            <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
            <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
            <active>1</active>
        </connection>
    </default_setup>
```